# Yocto: do_rootfs fails because can't find the package I'm building

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Trying to add a new package in my target `Intel` platform with `Yocto` build system. New package is `intel-cmt-cat` and its source code is taken from [here](https://github.com/intel/intel-cmt-cat). After looking at examples, I created my simple recipe file:

```
% cat intel-cmt-cat_4.1.0.bb
SUMMARY = "Short summary"
DESCRIPTION = "Short description."
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=c63eb1250e8724441150d665efe12012"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/intel/intel-cmt-cat.git;protocol=https"
SRCREV = "30fadea5cb82ff99f56e46172c7d20fdb24b2338"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

Nothing fancy, and *should* work, however it fails (I removed lengthy dnf command, made it short):

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf.

dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c dnf.conf package1 package2 ... intel-cmt-cat
...
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for:
not found modules for:
not found deltainfo for:
not found updateinfo for:
oe-repo: using metadata from Thu 04 Mar 2021 07:12:38 PM UTC.
No module defaults found
No match for argument: intel-cmt-cat
Error: Unable to find a match

...
ERROR: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

It appears to me that `do_rootfs()` function is failing. I checked the build directory, and can see that the sources have been fetched and built. However the later steps fail: as you see it is unable to locate my package (as far as I can say).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After reading manuals at yoctoproject.org, I came up with the following recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Short summary"
DESCRIPTION = "Short description."
LICENSE = "BSD"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=c63eb1250e8724441150d665efe12012"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/intel/intel-cmt-cat.git;protocol=https"
SRCREV = "30fadea5cb82ff99f56e46172c7d20fdb24b2338"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

do_compile() {
   oe_runmake PREFIX=/usr
}

do_install() {
   oe_runmake PREFIX=${D}/usr NOLDCONFIG=y install
   rm -rf ${D}/usr/man
   rm -rf ${D}/usr/include
}

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped"
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libpqos* ${bindir}/pqos* ${bindir}/rdtset"}
```

intel-cmt-cat does not use `cmake`, just good old `make` and Makefile.

I only rely on the package's `LDFLAGS` and don't pass any in the recipe, so this caused error during build:

*No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: ...*

In order to workaround this, add `TARGET_CC_ARCH` directive.

I explicitly call oe_runmake fuunction as I want to pass on a different `PREFIX` value (default is /usr/local); next in do_install I pass on NOLDCONFIG=y which will not invoke `ldconfig` and finally skips checking (via directive INSANE_SKIP) if generated binaries have not already been stripped. This is done because the Makefile already calls `install -s ...` and I didn't want to patch Makefile etc.